# How to have eager loading in linq join statement?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Below is the linq query wherein I want to retrieve the Team object when I select the employee. How can I achieve eager loading with linq join? Without the linq join statement, I am able to retrieve the Team object (eager loading).

```
Employee x = (from emp in context.Employees.Include("Team")
                     join role in context.Roles on 
                           emp.EmployeeId equals role.EmployeeId 
                     select emp ).Single();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you wish to return the Employee & the Team?

Comment: yes, i want to load employee and the team

Answer (score 2):

You could setup DataLoadOptions for the context. Something along these lines:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Role>(c => c.EmployeeId);
context.LoadOptions = options;
```

Here's an article that may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx